# android custom toolbar how to set back button be white?

Tags: android, button, toolbar, back

style/AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
</style>
```

style/ActivityCustomToolbarTheme:

```
<style name="ActivityCustomToolbarTheme" parent="AppTheme">
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
     app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

i set the `app:theme` to this,but it always is black.if set `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark`,it is grey.

other activity that don't custom is ok,but how to set the custom theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Use this

    protected void showBackButton() {
        mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        final Drawable upArrow = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_back); (R.drawable.ic_back==> your own drawable .png)
        mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
```

Comment: Does this mean that it's a bug?

Comment: No.. above code is useful when you required white color arrow  in specific activity/fragment not in entire application.

You can achieve this through themes:

<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item> 
  //the rest of your codes...
</style>

Comment: The name of the resource was changed in the 23.2.0 support library. Modify abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha to abc_ic_ab_back_material

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
     app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

I.e. using `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` (instead of  `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark`) when setting the toolbar's `app:theme`.

Comment: I've included an example in the answer. What results do you get?