# How to set Toolbar text and hamburger icon to be white?

Tags: android

Toolbar text and hamburger icon is in black color and I want in white color.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420991/android-custom-toolbar-how-to-set-back-button-be-white), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969424/how-to-set-toolbar-text-and-back-arrow-color) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954586/change-title-color-in-toolbar) solution but nothing worked.
Source code link: https://github.com/vaibhavsingh97/Solucion/tree/master/Android%20Basic%20Nanodegree/Project%206/TourGuide

Styles.xml

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        style="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_play"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Android Studio: 3.0 Canary 9
SDK used for build: 26

[image]

Comment: what happens if you set text color primary and text color secondary inside app theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Activity, you can use

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

If you love to choose xml for both title color & back arrow white just add this style in style.xml .

```
 <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And toolbar look like :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
  />
```

**UPDATE**

try this

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

So check `<item name="color">@android:color/black</item>` line. Just change your desired color here.

Comment: Still the problem remains same, only Tool bar text color changed to white

Answer (score 0):

try darkActionBar theme as toolbar style in XML file